# What does it mean to set file permission?

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

In layman's terms, what does it mean to set file permission when installing magento2? I understand it's something we need to do to make it work, but I was wondering what it is / why do we actually do it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not just in Magento. It is used otherwise as well. We use permissions to determine who can access and modify the files and directories stored in their file systems. There could be many reasons for it but mainly because of security purposes or to restrict certain users from modifying something important in our directory. In Linux, the owner of a file can change the permissions for user ( u ), group ( g ), or others ( o ) by adding ( + ) or subtracting ( - ) the read, write, and execute permissions.

This is the simplest understanding of the concept.